# Upload CSV file into MySQL database (error)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to insert CSV file into MySql but I'm getting an error.

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string,

My database table is:

```
:s_no    :name    :id   :
:1       :Lim     :678  :
:2       :Mary    :623  :
:3       :Mimi    :4124 :
```

The **number** is AUTO_INCREMENT, I wanted instead the Name And ID only.

```
<?php
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","skpj");

  if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
    if($_FILES['file']['name'])
    {
      $filename = explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name']);
      if ($filename[1] == 'csv')
      {
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
        while ($data = fgetcsv($handle))
        {
          $item1 = mysql_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);
          $item2 = mysql_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);
          $sql="INSERT into student( s_no, name, id) value ('','$item1','$item2')";
          mysql_query($connect, $sql);
        }
        fclose($handle);

        print "Done";
      }
    }
  }

?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <p>Upload CSV: <input type="file" name="file" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Import" /></p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: missing form action

Comment: I didn't get this line '*The "number" is AUTO_INCREMENT, so i wanted to instead to Name And ID only*". Please Explain.

Comment: The "s_no" is AUTO_INCREMENT, so i wanted to instead to Name And ID only.

in the database the field "s_no" is auto generate. i just need to instead in name and id field only.

Answer (score 1):

The connection is the second parameter.

```
mysql_real_escape_string( $data[0], $connect);
```

Also remember it is a deprecated function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: okey.. i did it. no error. but the data still did not instead. 
have any idea what can i do??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 mysql_real_escape_string("string")
```

means

```
mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);
```

Comment: okey.. i did it. no error. but the data still did not instead. 
have any idea what can i do??

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **mysqli** then

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data[0]);
```

if you are use **mysql**

```
mysql_real_escape_string( $data[0]);
```

Comment: okey.. i did it. no error. but the data still did not instead. 
have any idea what can i do??